# make if statement more DRY

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to make this code more DRY.
What's the best way to go about it?

```
if(array_key_exists($var1, $arr)) {
    $var1 = 'etc/'. $var1;
}

if(array_key_exists($var2, $arr)) {
    $var2 = 'etc/'. $var2;
}

if(array_key_exists($var3, $arr)) {
    $var3 = 'etc/'. $var3;
}

if(array_key_exists($var4, $arr)) {
    $var4 = 'etc/'. $var4;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, whenever you find yourself with variables with incrementing names like that, you should be using an array, not separate variables. Then you can easily loop over the array.

So replace all the `$varN` variables with an array `$vars`, and do:

```
foreach ($vars as &$v) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $arr)) {
        $v = '/etc/' . $v;
    }
}
```

The reference variable `&$v` makes assigning to the variable update the array.

You can also use `array_map()` with the array:

```
$vars = array_map(function($v) use ($arr) {
    if (array_key_exists($v, $arr)) {
        return '/etc/' . $v;
    } else {
        return $v;
    }
}, $vars);
```